# Plotly Sunburst chart with percentages

Tags: python-3.x, charts, plotly, plotly-python, sunburst-diagram

I would like to create a Sunburst chart, corresponding to the following:

[image]

Where:

- B is 70% of A
- C is 20% of B
- D is 50% of B

I looked at the plotly [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/sunburst-charts/) but the examples provided only used either use a dataset or a `values` argument which I don't understand how it works.

Do someone have an example I can rely on, that is similar to what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 6):

There is a setting that allows percentages to be added to labels, which would make this possible. `fig.update_traces(textinfo="label+percent parent")` The answer is a modified code based on the example in the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/sunburst-charts/#basic-sunburst-plot-with-plotlyexpress).

```
import plotly.express as px
data = dict(
    character=["Eve", "Cain", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam", "Abel", "Awan", "Enoch", "Azura"],
    parent=["", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth", "Seth", "Eve", "Eve", "Awan", "Eve" ],
    value=[10, 14, 12, 10, 2, 6, 6, 4, 4])

fig = px.sunburst(
    data,
    names='character',
    parents='parent',
    values='value',
)

fig.update_traces(textinfo="label+percent parent")

fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    height=500,
    width=500
)
                  
fig.show()
```

[image]